# How to serialize a map in yaml/pgm file type to get data/posegraph file type

Tags: ros2, localization, pgm

I am trying to use the Slam toolbox localization node with ROS2 Humble on Ubunto on a dual-boot laptop, previously I used the AMCL node of the nav2 stack but wanted to try something different to see the localization performance.
But when I do not know how to transform the .yaml/.pgm files to .data/.posegraph files correctly.
Tried to do it with the SlamToolboxPlugin for rviz2, by first publishing a map with the map server and then serializing the map. But when I try to deserialize the map, either with the deserialize button or using it in the Slam_Toolbox_localization node params file, the node crashes. With the following error in the terminal:

```
[ERROR] [localization_slam_toolbox_node-1]: process has died [pid 23558, exit code -11, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/slam_toolbox/localization_slam_toolbox_node --ros-args -r __node:=slam_toolbox --params-file <correct-path>/config/mapper_params_localization.yaml --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n_gacl_d -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static -r /initialpose:=/set_pose'].
```

I also tried the OGM2PGBM package from MigVega to serialize the map, but do not know how to build/run it in ROS2.

I do not know where the problem is, possible that the files (posegraph/data) are not correct (how to check this?), or that something else goes wrong. It did work when I made a map with a lidar, by using the Slam Toolbox online sync node and driving around in simulation. But have not succeded in transforming the yaml/pgm to data/posegraph files.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get .data/.posegraph from .yaml/.pgm but you can do it via SlamToolbox's rviz plugin *while you are doing mapping*.

As soon as you finish the mapping, do not stop `slam_toolbox` node, go to its rviz plugin and enter a name for serialized version of the map, then press `Serialize Map`. That will save .data/.posegraph files on disk.

[image]